# Object of class Magento\Framework\View\Page\Title could not be converted to string

Tags: magento2.3, magento-upgrade, renderer

We just recently tested upgrading from M2.2.4 to M2.3.7 and have ironed out most of the issues, however when trying to load a page, we get the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Object of class
> Magento\Framework\View\Page\Title could not be converted to string in
> /app/code/CleverSoft/Base/Model/Renderer.php:141
> Stack trace: #0
> /app/code/CleverSoft/Base/Model/Renderer.php(141):
> str_replace(Array, Array, '<meta name="%na...') #1
> /app/code/CleverSoft/Base/Model/Renderer.php(112):
> CleverSoft\Base\Model\Renderer->renderMetadata() #2
> /vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Page.php(250):
> CleverSoft\Base\Model\Renderer->renderHeadContent() #3
> /vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Layout.php(171):
> Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page->render(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
> #4 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58):
> Ma in
> /app/code/CleverSoft/Base/Model/Renderer.php
> on line 141

The function it is referring to within Renderer.php is:

```
public function renderMetadata()
    {
        $result = '';
        foreach ($this->pageConfig->getMetadata() as $name => $content) {
            $metadataTemplate = $this->getMetadataTemplate($name);
          if (!$metadataTemplate) {
                continue;
            }
            $content = $this->processMetadataContent($name, $content);
            if ($content) {
               $result .= str_replace(['%name', '%content'], [$name, $content], $metadataTemplate);
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }
```

With the mentioned line 141 being `$result .= str_replace(['%name', '%content'], [$name, $content], $metadataTemplate);`

Just playing with it and changing the code to:

```
public function renderMetadata()
    {
        $result = '';
        return $result;
    }
```

Allows the pages to load but, some elements end up broken like the navigation menus and whatnot. The above is not a solution, so anyone has any ideas. What did I do to allow for the object to be converted to a string?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to try this code.

```
protected $emailfilter;

public function __construct(
        .....
        \Magento\Email\Model\Template\Filter $filter,
        .....)
    {
        $this->emailfilter = $filter;
    }

public function renderMetadata()
    {

        $result = '';
        foreach ($this->pageConfig->getMetadata() as $name => $content) 
        {
            $metadataTemplate = $this->getMetadataTemplate($name);
            if(!$metadataTemplate) 
            {
               continue;
            }
            $content = $this->processMetadataContent($name, $content);
            if ($content) 
            {
               $this->emailfilter->setVariables(['%name' => $name,'%content' => $content]);
               $result = $this->emailfilter->filter($metadataTemplate);
            }
         }
    return $result;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for helping! I implemented the protected designation, the __construct listings, however not sure how to implement the `renderMetadata()` function. I first tried with none of the previous function and just using yours as displayed, but it gave `Undefined variable: name` on `$this->emailfilter->setVariables(['%name' => $name,'%content' => $content]);` -- I then tried a few variations of mixing in your code with the original function with no success. Is there anything else to add to the `renderMetadata()` function?

Comment: I update the code kindly check and let me know.

Comment: Thank you! Your changes allowed for the page to load, however it didn't end up displaying the content much like when I just changed the `renderMetadata()` to only having `$result = ''; return $result;` inside it -- no error, just no block either. The Menu isn't displaying and the footer isn't displaying so I assume it's having an issue loading these elements as widgets. Any ideas? For instance, the menu that isn't loading comes in via this: `{{widget type="CleverSoft\CleverMegaMenus\Block\Widget\Megamenu" menu="main_menu"}}` Thanks as always!

Comment: That is from third party extension so that need to check what actually problem there. If answer help you to resolve the issues please accept as solution and upvote so it will help other in community.

Answer (score 0):

What about trying something like this for each of your name and content ? Not sure about the syntax but here is the idea

```
if(get_class($name) == 'Magento\Framework\View\Page\Title'){
    $realName = $name->get();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some custom module affect to value of title. I think it's a good idea to debug to see what the value of title is.